# MVEL case-insensentive

Tags: java, mvel

anybody knows how to adjust MVEL to use case-insensetive comparison?

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Name", "Igor");

String property = "name";
Object res = MVEL.eval(property, map);
System.out.println(res);
```

In this case I got an exception:

> Error: could not access: name; in class: java.util.HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

MVEL is case-sensitive because Java is. You don't have choice.